# Create hibernate query for selected values of a selected column

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to create a query for this specific case.

I have table `QuizData1` saved in database using hibernate.

```
id  answer  optA    optB    question    quizname
------------------------------------------------- 
1   ans1    opt1    opt2    question1   gk

2   ans2    opt3    opt4    question2   java

3   ans3    opt5    opt6    question3   other

4   ans4    opt7    opt8    question4   java
```

I want to get all values for quiz `java` only. I tried

```
List quizlist = ssn.createQuery("FROM QuizData1 WHERE quizname=java").list();
```

But it is returning `null`.

Comment: Could you share the corresponding entity class?

Comment: I improved the formatting of post for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HQL , you should use the java class name and property name of the mapped @Entity instead of the actual table name and column name.
e.g.

```
@Entity
public class App implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="app_id")
    private String appId;
}
```

The query should be
`session.createQuery("FROM App where appId='app').list;`. Also don't forget to add quotes around the string values.

Comment: thanks...i was missing single quotes